# Facebook Graph API event-id/comments?since=2014-02-01&until=2014-02-10 , Date filter has no effect

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

1. I am trying to bring comments made on a particular event by targeting this URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/1466384840257158/comments`
2. I am passing the user_access_token
3. I have two comments at present on this event made on the same
   day(2014-03-29)
4. Now I try to pass a date which should bring an empty data result/object
   like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/1466384840257158/comments?since=2011-01-01&until=2014-01-10`
5. This request has no effect, it still shows me the two comment made
   on the 29th
6. I have tried the same kind of date range on my user-id/feed and it
   gave me an empty data object.
7. Finally i tried event-id/feed (before trying date filter) and it
   gave me the following error

.

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.", 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "code": 2
    }
}
```

Could you please guide me about date filter on that particular query (point4) or if you have any other idea to use date filter on comments made for an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments use [Cursor-based Pagination](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging), so you cannot use `since` or `until` on the comments endpoint (these parameters would work f.ex. for the `feed` endpoint).

To get the comments in a time range you have to fetch all comments from NOW to the start of the time range, f.ex. with  `https://graph.facebook.com/1466384840257158/comments?filter=stream&limit=1000`+paging (the `filter=stream` will order the result with the timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try first to filter by notifications?... notifications allows you to add parameters like since. For example (using Facebook pages):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID?fields=notifications.since(2015-3-31 00:00:00).limit(250).include_read(true)&{id,created_time,updated_time,unread,object,link}&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN
```

Once you got the json data, loop through data, get the ID  and send a second request but this time using the PAGEID_POSTID edge. Something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID_POSTID/comments?fields=id,from{name,id},message,can_remove,created_time&limit=1000
```

Voahla!... there's no need to read every comment!...

Note 1: A Page access token is required, along with the manage_pages permission

Note 2: Use the parameter/field include_read to get all the notifications, even the already readed

Note 3: In the second request, use the parameter/field "filter=stream" to order the posts and get the comments made in the name of your page

Note 4: Don't forget to control the asynchronicity once you loop!

Note 5: Notifications duplicate posts,  use an array to avoid to read more than one time the postUse the parameter/field include_read to get all the notifications, even the already readed

Answer (score 0):

**USING SINCE UNTIL FOR COMMENTS on GROUP**
If you want to use since and until for comments, it is not possible directly for a group. So, First you can apply it for status(feed) and then get the comments for that feed.
This works for me:

```
{group_id}/?fields=feed.since(08/25/2016).until(08/31/2016){from,comments{from,message}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it's too late. But, Yeah it works  in the graph api version 3.3.

for example: if you wanna get comments on a post of a Facebook page you can do it like this:

- You have to use page Access-token
- The get Graph Request : post_id/comments?since=some_date